# Built-in Sitemap on Multi-site install produces 404?

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, 404-error, sitemap

We have a subdirectory multi-site install. Some documentation I found says that WordPress has a built in sitemap, at /sitemap.xml. Trying to access `domain.com/blog/sitemap.xml` produces a WordPress `This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?` 404 page.

The rewrite rules we are using (one set for each virtual sub directory):

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*\.php)$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/blog/(.*) /wordpress/index.php [L]
```

I am assuming that sitemap.xml is not actually a real file, and that requests for it should get routed to index and processed, which appears to be happening.

Was the built in site-map removed or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Wordpress, the core software does not create a default sitemap to my knowledge, I think if you use wordpress.com they do add one for you though

Comment: That's probably the problem then, I found a page that was an official documentation page saying it was automatically generated. It wasn't clear from the page that it was only wordpress.com hosted sites.